# Why "undefined method `create' for #<Array:..." using Paperclip multiple upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm trying to save multiple `logos` for my model `cover` through a form.
Following this tutorial : [Handling file upload with ROR 5](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/handling-file-upload-using-ruby-on-rails-5-api/),    I created a model `logos` and properly set association between `logos` and `cover`

The issue I can't solve is when i'm trying to save the `cover` instance I get :

> > [image]

The error seems to be in `save attachment` method...

Here is my code :

**cover/_form**

```
           = simple_form_for [current_user, @book, @cover], html: { multipart: true } do |f|

               = f.label :logos, 'Votre logo', class: "field-label center"

               = f.file_field :logos, multiple: true, class: 'text input-border hidden-always'
            = f.submit "enregistrer", class: "button w-button", data_wait: "Patientez svp"
```

**logo.rb**

```
class Logo < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :file
  belongs_to :cover
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file

end
```

**cover.rb**

```
class Cover < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :logos, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessor :logos

  def save_attachments(params)
    params[:logos].each do |doc|
      self.logos.create(:file => doc)
    end
  end
end
```

**covers_controller.rb**

```
 class CoversController < ApplicationController
   def create
    if @cover.save
      @cover.save_attachments(cover_params) if params[:cover][:logos]
      ...
    end
   end

    private 

    def cover_params
       params.require(:cover).permit(:name, logos: [])

    end
 end
end
```

**UPDATE**

If I change the value of `attr_accessor :logos` to  `attr_accessor :logos_data`, I get this

[image]

Comment: I guess the issue is with line `attr_accessor :logos`, try changing it to something like `attr_accessor :logos_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Cover` model try changing the name of `attr_accessor :logos` to something else